# Can't fetch data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I can't fetch data from my Firebase database with this simple method :

```
getLists(callback) {
    let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(this.userId).collection("lists");
    this.unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let lists = [];
        console.log('1');
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log('2');
            console.log("This message doesn't appear in console...");
        });
        console.log('3');
        callback(lists);
    });
}
```

As you can see, the code doesn't run through "snapshot.forEach()" section.
Why? I see a lot of examples on the Internet which uses this method. Only '1' and '2' appear in console...

I'm following this video tutorial which did the exact same things but it works for him (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NCnO5a3v0c&t=388s).

I'm using Expo CLI with my Android mobile phone and Firebase v7.9.0.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We actually have no way to see why your code doesn't run through the `forEach` section, and will need your help to tell us what *does* happen. If you put a similar `console.log` before `let lists = []`, does it print? If not, can you show a document that you'd expect to be matched by this query? Are there any error messages printed in the console (i.e. does the user have permission to read this content)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Yes, if I put a ```console.log()``` before ```let lists = []```, it prints and there's no error message...

Comment: Next step, I'd add a second callback for errors as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors If that also shows no errors, it's most likely that there really are no documents for the read operation.

Comment: You're right! I tested with this to fetch data with fake Firebase collection "test" : ```firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(this.userId).collection("test");``` and we're in the same situation than before.
I suppose that I miss something. The only difference between the tutorial video and my projet is about the creation of my second Firebase collection "lists": I had to generate an id to save my new collection.

Comment: I'm not sure what that last comment means. If you have a different test that gives clearer results, please edit the question (there's a link right under it) to show that. If you don't see an error in the error handler, but still think there should be results, it might be useful if you also include a screenshot that shows a document you expect to be returned (including its full path) in the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I finally created an other collection simpler than the one created by the tutorial video author. It works with it :

```
getLists(callback) {
        let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("lists").orderBy("name");
        this.unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let lists = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                lists.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
            });
            callback(lists);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```